# Android: Unable to find optional library: org.apache.http.legacy

Tags: android, cordova, sdk, android-gradle-plugin, deprecated

I created a Cordova app and I need to use expansion files for the google play store.
To use this expansion files, I added the [xapkreader plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/com.intel.xapkreader).
Now, when I want to build my project (`cordova build android`), I get the following error:

> package org.apache.http does not exist

I tried to add

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

to my build.gradle. But then I got

> A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
>
> > Unable to find optional library: org.apache.http.legacy

Also, I put my `org.apache.http.legacy.jar` in every lib folder I found.

The optional.json exists in my android-23 sdk folder, too.

Does somebody have an idea how I could fix it?

**Values:**

- minSdkVersion: 16
- targetSdkVersion: 25
- Cordova: 6.0.0
- Gradle version: 2.2.1

Comment: try this to add in gradle:   compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6') {
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
    }
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5'

Comment: I added this code to my dependencies, but the error is still there...

Answer (score 0):

Use this alternative:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, the error is still there.

Comment: Which gradle version are you using?

Comment: I use the gradle version 2.2.1